# Can I use SQL to store my Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, sql, object

I'm new to programming, and I have been programming a small project with vanilla javascript, but I was using a lot of document.getElementById() tags, and I stored all of these in a javascript object, on a seperate file, but I was wondering If I could Just store that object on a SQL file, to make my project more organized.

I'm not sure if that's possible, I know that SQL stores data, so would I be able to store my JS object on a sql file, and import that object into my seperate Javascript files?

I'm trying to make sure if I can do what I want to do before I decide to start learning sql, but If it does do what I need, I was going to start incorporating it for organization, so I can learn it as I create projects.

Comment: Seems somewhat possible: https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-sql.htm

Comment: The Term SQL is pretty broad,.  MySQL, WebSQL, sqLite etc.  And generally speaking, apart from the WebSQL you will need a back end  Node / PHP etc, & WebSQL is been deprecated :(,.  So your questions needs a little bit more detail to give better advice.  Also is this mutli-user, or single user.  If it's multi-user, again you will need a back end..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function to convert your javascript objects into strings. However, it is important to note that [the only items within the javascript object that are converted into strings are](https://www.json.org/json-en.html): objects, arrays, strings, numbers, and values that are: null, true, or false. If you have references to functions or classes that have been instantiated, then these will be lost. You can convert the string back into a javascript object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

One thing to consider before you do this is whether or not you need to perform database queries on the data that you are storing within the javascript object. If you need to search on the javascript object's data, then you should store the information directly within tables in the database. If you don't need to search on it, then converting the data to a string and saving it should be fine to do. Since it sounds as though you are using the data for your own purposes, doing this should be fine since extracting all of the data from the database shouldn't be an intensive task. Also, you can write your own scripts to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you can store as a `JSON Blob`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/store-json-documents-in-sql-tables?view=sql-server-ver15